# WCF 4.0 - Returning JSON WebFaultException with REST Service Template

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception, rest

I am using the WCF REST Service Template 40(CS). I am throwing WebFaultExceptions as such:

```
throw new WebFaultException<string>("Error Message", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```

However, when I test this with my client, everything is being returned as a Http Status Code of 500 and the response is XML. I can see the error message in the XML response. When I make a call correctly, I get a 200 response and the response is in JSON which is correct given the way my config and ServiceContract are setup.

The only way I can get the HTTP Status Code to be 400 for the Bad Request is to do this:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
```

I still cannot get the exception to return as JSON.

**Edit** Adding signature for more information:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "myendpoint")]
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: If this were working correctly, the status code should have been 400 (bad request). Can you enable tracing to see if there is something else going on which is preventing the WebFaultException<string> from being processed? I just created a new project with the REST Service template, added (ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json) to one of the operations, and added the same line you have - and the response came back encoded as JSON, not XML.

Comment: Could it be that I am doing this in my code: `catch(WebFaultException<string> ex) { throw; }` ? I can also add additional config information if needed.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem; Can you post the signature of the operation contract (with the [WebGet/WebInvoke] attribute)?

Comment: I added my method signature. All of them are POST and have a similar setup.

Answer (score 4):

In you web.config set the value of AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled to false

```
<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" />
```

Set the response format to json (which you have done already)

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

Answer (score 4):

When `WebHttpBehavior.FaultExceptionEnabled` is set to `true`, `WebFaultException` will result in a 200 response with the fault rendered as XML and not JSON, despite the `automaticFormatSelectionEnabled` configuration setting or response format attribute settings.  The MSDN documentation does not mention this and is misleading in that it states that this property is only related to the 500 response code.

Comment: Setting `WebHttpBehavior.FaultExceptionEnabled` to `false` helped for me. Otherwise, I would always get the 500 response code on every `WebFaultException` thrown.

Answer (score 0):

for those still having this issue. This worked for me

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json";
throw new System.ServiceModel.Web.WebFaultException<Response>(
          new Response(false,"was not found", ""),System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```

Comment: What is `Response`?