# Return Different JSON in WCF method on error

Tags: c#, json, wcf, exception

I have a method which return a class cono in Json format

```
  [DataContract]
public class Cono
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public Companies[] companies;

}
public class Companies
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string cono;
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string name;
}

      [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetCompanies?requestKey={requestKey}",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public Cono GetCompanies(string requestKey);
```

this method first validate request key  if it is correct it returns data like this:

```
{
companies: [
{
cono: "001",
name: "Company001"
}
]
}
```

but if request key is not correct I want to return an error code in json like this

```
{-100}
```

How can I change the return type of the method to Int or how can I return desired data in the above format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258545/wcf-4-0-returning-json-webfaultexception-with-rest-service-template

Comment: Surely if you want to make this RESTful you should return a 401 Http Error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the return type of your method to `Stream` (*`public Stream GetCompanies(string requestKey);`*) and write a method

```
static Stream ToJson(object o)
{
    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);

    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentLength = data.Length;
    return new MemoryStream(data);
}
```

Then, in your method, you can use it as

```
........
return ToJson(anyObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about changing your return type to something like this?

```
[DataContract]
public class Cono
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public Companies[] companies;

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public Error error;    
}

public class Error
{
    public int code;
    public string message;
}
```

Then if you have an error, `companies` will be null and the `error` will be set.  If you don't have an error, `error` will be null and `companies` will be set.